# JxBrowser v6.15 crashes when instantiating Browser()

Tags: java, jxbrowser

No changes in our code -- only change was using the 6.15 libraries instead of the 6.14.2. Running in OS X (10.12.6), Java 8u111. It's a hard crash of the JVM, with the only clue being

```
 [1004/115956.927413:WARNING:dns_config_service_posix.cc(154)] dns_config has unhandled options!
Received signal 11 SEGV_MAPERR 000000000000
 [0x000199717cec]
 [0x000199717be1]
 [0x7fffb7b10b3a]
 [0x700006312d88]
 [0x000106fa933d]
 [0x000106fa933d]
[end of stack trace]
```

Stepping through the debugger, the crash is happening on this line of the 4-arg Browser() constructor:

```
 context.a().start();
```

Seems like this was an issue in Chromium 59 back in July, but it shows as fixed, so I'm surprised to see it in Chromium 60.

Any clues on how to resolve this?